# "Seductive" as an adjective for describing snake

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adjectives, american-english, british-english

I would really appreciate if some native English speaker help me in clearing my doubt.

Recently, in one of Indian English newspaper the column writer wrote the following: "A scary sci-fi scenario. And one which could have its roots in a long-ago Garden where a seductive serpent offered Eve an Apple with a capital ‘A’."
My point is how much correct is the word choice of "SEDUCTIVE" in stead of "DECEIVING" to describe the snake especially in case of Adam and Eve story. Here is the full article: http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/jugglebandhi/summing-up-thanks-to-machines-we-can-no-longer-add-two-and-two-together/

Thanks.

Comment: (1) The Bible does not specify an 'apple'. (2) 'Deceiving' does not work too well here as a pure descriptor for reasons of style, and the non-participial adjective 'deceptive' doesn't either. (3) 'Seductive' has the sense 'appealing to wrong indulgence [of appetites]', which is not synonymous with 'deceptive'. (4) 'Seductive serpent' certainly works well, but if one wants to reference deceit, 'deceitful' is probably best.

Comment: The snake "Kaa" was described as seductive in a recent review of "The Jungle Book movie".

Answer (score 5):

In American English, either seductive or deceptive would be all right, depending on which attribute of the snake you wanted to highlight.

I would use seductive if you want to focus on the appeal of the apple, but deceptive if you want to refer to the snake's dishnonesty.

[Deceptive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deceptive):

> intended to make someone believe something that is not true
>
> likely to make someone believe something that is not true

[Seductive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seductive):

> making someone do or want something : very attractive

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, I just noticed your comment covered everything I just said. Sorry, I should have read it first.